# How to connect to multiple servers while maintaining current connection?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am writing an application in java,

The way this application works is that it must connect to every single server in a private network, given only one starting port and IP,

The first thing I do in this application is connect to an IP and port specified by the command line,
(by starting a new thread)

Once I make this connection, I receive a list of more IP's and ports which I must connect to.

However, I must also keep the connection to the current IP and port "open" by sending it strings (specified by a protocol every 30 seconds);

Here is the problem: Once I received the list from my initial connection, I enter a  while(true) loop that runs infinitely and sends a specified string every 30 seconds, (this lets the other end know that I am still there)

however because the loop runs infinitely, I am not able to connect to the other IP's and ports because I need to break out of the loop in order to start a new thread to connect to another IP.

My code is somewhat cumbersome so I will try to explain it with pseudo code:
(If it helps, I can edit to post my actual code)

```
Main:
    port = args[0]
    IP = args[1]
    try{
        new Thread
    }


Thread:
    connect(Ip, Port)
    recieve IPlist
    while(true){ <---- this is where I get stuck
        send ping every 30 seconds
    }
```

I want to be able to maintain the connection AND create new ones.
I suppose this is more of a design problem than a coding one.

*Also I hope my question is well written, if you downvote it please tell me how I can improve it.*

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to maintain the connection AND create new ones.

You need a loop which does both in the same loop,

```
while(true){ <---- this is where I get stuck
    open any connection which need openning
    send ping every 30 seconds
    any thing else.
}
```

This has a problem that if a connection blocks, it can cause all your connection to fail to send heartbeats, but it is simple to implement.

OR

You can have a separate thread manage each connection, sending heartbeats as required, while you main thread only owrries about which connection to make.

OR

You have a thread for sending heartbeats to all open connections, while you main thread manages which ones should be open.

What you feel is simplest is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think, following Observer Design Pattern probably you can look for a solution.
Subject- Class which will have the first connection with given IP and port in command line argument.
Observer - Class maintaining list of Subject.
like below ->

Step 1

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Subject {

   private List<Observer> observers = new ArrayList<Observer>();
   private int state;

   public int getState() {
      return state;
   }

   public void setState(int state) {
      this.state = state;
      notifyAllObservers();
   }

   public void attach(Observer observer){
      observers.add(observer);      
   }

   public void notifyAllObservers(){
      for (Observer observer : observers) {
         observer.update();
      }
   }    
}

Step 2

public abstract class Observer {
   protected Subject subject;
   public abstract void update();
}

Step 3
Create concrete observer classes

BinaryObserver.java

public class BinaryObserver extends Observer{

   public BinaryObserver(Subject subject){
      this.subject = subject;
      this.subject.attach(this);
   }

   @Override
   public void update() {
      System.out.println( "Binary String: " + Integer.toBinaryString( subject.getState() ) ); 
   }
}
I have taken this example from following link
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm
```